# Is this sql query valid (many-to-many relation)

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I'm just wandering is the following query valid. I have one table called professor which contains professors. Table subject contains subjects. Many-to-many relation is realized with professor_subject table, which contains professor_id and subject_id fields.

Now I need to see which professor is teaching which subject. I wrote this SQL query:

```
SELECT concat(professor.name, " ", professor.surname) as "Professor", 
       subject.name as "Subject" 
FROM professor_subject, subject, professor 
WHERE subject.id = subject_id 
    and professor.id = professor_id;
```

Is this query valid ? I mean, will it always do what I want ? I'm little suspicious because I didn't use JOIN keyword.

Thanks :)

Comment: While Justin Niessner's answer is correct, you don't necessarily need the JOIN keyword for joins. You can write his solution also as `select concat(professor.name, " ", professor.surname) as "Professor", subject.name as "Subject"
from professor, subject, professor_subject
where professor.id = professor_subject.professor_id
and professor_subject.subject_id = subject.id`

Comment: @AlexMonthy: That's what I wrote, except I'm lazy so I've ommited "professor_subject." before subject_id and professor_id :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's nothing here that correlates a professor to a subject. You're using a cross join with no criteria (not sure if subject_id and professor_id in the where clause are table values or query parameters). You need something like:

```
select concat(professor.name, " ", professor.surname) as "Professor",
       subject.name as "Subject"
from professor
inner join professor_subject
    on professor.id = professor_subject.professor_id
inner join subject
    on professor_subject.subject_id = subject.id
```

Comment: Student ? I think you mean subject. subject_id and professor_id are fields from professor_subject table - I use them to correlate professor to subject. Anyway, thanks for you query ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that subject_id and professor_id are in professor_subject, you're ok.  Before the JOIN keyword was available in all versions of SQL (Oracle pre-9i for example), this was how joins were done.